# Looping through an array of API values for API GET request in Python

Tags: python, api, loops, get, python-requests

I have an array of ice cream flavors I want to iterate over for an API GET request.  How do I loop through an array such as [vanilla, chocolate, strawberry] using the standard API request below?

```
import requests

url = "https://fakeurl.com/values/icecreamflavor/chocolate?"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer (STRING)',
  '(STRING)': '(STRING)'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

my_list = (response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try string formatting on your url. You could loop through your array of ice-cream flavors, change the url in each loop and perform API GET request on the changed url.

```
import requests

iceCreamFlavors = ["vanilla", "chocolate", "strawberry"]
url = "https://fakeurl.com/values/icecreamflavor/{flavor}?"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer (STRING)',
  '(STRING)': '(STRING)'
}
my_list = []

for flavor in iceCreamFlavors:
    response = requests.request("GET", url.format(flavor=flavor), headers=headers, data = payload)
    my_list.append(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```